# Linux - running root installed program as non-root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm, root

I installed RVM, then Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.5 as super-user. I can access the program as root but not as a normal user.

```
# rails -v 
Rails 4.2.5

$ rails -v
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

Would I need to delete and reinstall the program or is there a workaround?  Sorry this is a newbie question I know but I'm lost.

Comment: @fedorqui Using curl and RVM

Comment: Can you specify the exact commands? Have you try with the `sudo apt-get...` I mentioned above?

Comment: @fedorqui sudo apt-get install give me an older version.  I wanted the most up to date version of Ruby and Rails hence the reason for RVM

Comment: What do you get if you say `which ruby`? Also `ruby --version` or similar to know what is the installed version, because it clearly conflicts with the one `rails` expects you to have.

Comment: I already have the most up to date versions on my machine. I can only access it using root login.

Comment: which ruby    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby

Comment: rvm adds a line to your bashrc or profile telling the logged in envronment where to find rvm-centric packages. Should look something like this: [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] - but instead of home will have your root path.  Do you ahve that in your users .bash_profile?

Comment: As @trh says, try to logout and log in again after adding this line into `.bash_profile`.

Comment: `ruby --version ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
`

Comment: @fedorqui @trh sorry, couldn't work out how to edit `.bash_profile`
Found it easier to reinstall. Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you especially need a work-around? If not, it would probably be easiest to re-install using sudo. The reason is that when logged in as root, programs install only for root user. When using sudo, they install for all users.

To avoid using apt-get, you could try using `sudo curl`

See here for more information:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/258057/installed-application-as-root-unable-to-use-by-other-user

Comment: Thanks @neallred Re-installed as normal user